# MVC Entity Framework, Query returns null

Tags: sql, entity-framework, model-view-controller, repository

Hi guys can you help me understand why i keep getting a null instead of get the value.
Need to receive the *saidaservicoid* to be able to update. I receive the value from the view but can't update *elemento*. Stays null.

Thanks in advance for the help.

[Database][image: 1]

[elementoRepository][image: 2]

public async Task UpdateElementoSaidaServicosAsync(AddSaidasServicoViewModel model)
{

```
        var saidaServico = await _context.SaidaServicos.FindAsync(model.SaidaServicoId);


        var elemento = await _context.Elementos.FindAsync(model.ElementoId);
        if (elemento == null)
        {
            return;
        }


        var updateElementoSaida = _context.Elementos.Where(e => e.Id == model.ElementoId).FirstOrDefault();
        if (updateElementoSaida == null)
        {
            updateElementoSaida = new Elemento
            {
                saidaServico = saidaServico,                                      

            };

            _context.Elementos.Update(updateElementoSaida);

        }
        else
        {

            int SaidaServicos = model.SaidaServicoId;
            updateElementoSaida.saidaServico = saidaServico;
        }

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();


        return;
    }
```

Comment: can you please paste a snippet instead of providing a link to screenshot?

Comment: What is null exactly? Do you mean that when you try to get the `_context.SaidaServicos.FindAsync(model.SaidaServicoId)` returns #null, or does it return an entity, but your update: `updateElementoSaida.saidaServico = saidaServico;` is being reached but the record in the database is not being updated?  If the entity is found but the update doesn't seem to catch, two possible reasons: a) you have EF change tracking proxies disabled in the DbContext. b) your runtime connection string is pointing to a different database than you are reviewing.

Comment: If the find call is returning #null then I'd check the runtime connection string  if you're sure the provided ID should exist.

Comment: _context.SaidaServicos.FindAsync(model.SaidaServicoId) returns #null. That is the problem. because i need to update Elemento with the SaidaServicoId. Because SaidaServicoId can have many elements.

Comment: What is the value of model.SaidaServicoId? If "0" where your view should be passing a valid ID, then I would check that your view is serializing the model correctly. If it is a valid ID (and there is a matching record) but your Find call returns Null, check your database connection string at runtime to ensure it's pointing at the same database instance you are checking against.

Comment: I found the problem. Im doing this on the event create. So if i try to pass the value, i won't be able because i didn't created yet.

Comment: The idea is, when i create saidaservico , the element's should receive the id from saidaservico. if the saidaservico isn't created yet it's impossible for them to receive. So i'm think off a delay, to the elemento receive the saidaservicoid after been insert to the Db

Answer (score 0):

Ok. the best way that i found to solve this issue was to get the last ID.

```
int SaidaServicos = _context.SaidaServicos.Max(item => item.Id);
```